# Matlab with large data set

Tags: sql, matlab, statistics, raw-data, nosql

I have some data I want to analyze in Matlab (R2013b). The data set however consists of 10 tab delimited text files (in total 16GB, each file contains the same fields). My idea was to insert all data into a single table using MSSQL. However, since I only need to do select queries, I was wondering if there is another method where I can use Azure Table Storage or some other NoSql alternative in Matlab. I expect my queries to be a little slow with a 16GB table (Core i7 860, 12GB RAM,HDD,Win8.1). Please let me know what I could use and what options I have concerning the import of large raw data sets for statistical analysis in terms of better performance and ease of use.

I understand multiple solutions could be useful, please provide some advice on what you would use and why. Of course also some tutorials for Matlab are also much appreciated (which I could not find yet while Googling myself ;) ).

Comment: As regards MATLAB tutorials, the [official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/) has everything you will need. It is also the first place to look for any functionality you may need.

Comment: yes I saw that their support for different databases is pretty comprehensive